# Работа с DOM структурой в Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, express

#### Ситуация:

У меня есть файл `index.html` в котором создана обычная html-страница с `‹input id="name"›`. Так же у меня есть файл `server.js` в котором запускается сервер на express по адресу `127.0.0.1:3000`.

#### Проблема:

Как мне работать с DOM структурой файла index.html из файла server.js. Например, мне нужно считать значение с `‹input id="input-field"›`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы передать значение поля ввода с клиента (index.html) на сервер (server.js) можно сделать submit формы.

Пример public/index.html:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <form action="/form_test" method="get">
        <input type="text" id="input-field" name="input-field" title="Тест параметра формы">
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Пример server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));
app.get('/form_test', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`input-field value is:  ${req.query['input-field']}`);
});
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Как на счет Cheerio? Загружаешь свой HTML и работаешь как с Jquery на клиенте.

https://cheerio.js.org/

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку **index.html** отображается на стороне клиента и значение в `‹input id="input-field"›` присутствует на стороне клиента, то и работать с ним надо на стороне клиента - в браузере.

Вам надо создать и добавить на страницу JavaScript код, который будет обрабатывать эти данные и пересылать вам на сервер используя стандартный механизм из http протокола.

Добавить скрипт можно используя тэг [script](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script), а пересылать данные можно используя [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)